# Bootstrap collapse : Close all children when root element is closed

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's collapse , by specifying `data-toggle` and `href` properties in my HTML tags. Using this, I built a multi-level collapsible list. This is the problem I'm facing:
Let's say Level 2 is the root, with Level 1 as the child of Level 2, and Level 0 as the child of Level 1. So we have a 2-level hierarchy. Initially, only Level 2 is shown ,with all children collapsed. When I click on Level 2, Level 1 is opened. Then, when I click on Level 1, Level 0 opens up. So far, fine. Now when I close Level 2, only Level 2 is shown as expected. But, the lower levels are not collapsed, **they're only hidden**. If I open Level 2 again, it shows me both Level 1 and Level 0 (as Level 0 was opened previously).

I want it such that when Level 2 is clicked, only Level 1 is shown always, not Level 0. Level 0 should be shown only when Level 1 is clicked.

Here's the code:

```
        <a href="#target1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">{{.}}</a>
        <div class="collapse" id="target1">
                    <a href="target2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">{{state}}<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="target2">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">{{name}}</a>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use jquery to accomplish this as shown below.  i have used bootstraps functionality of collapse element events: `hidden.bs.collapse` which is triggered when a collapse element is hidden.

another sidenote:
i think you have a typo in your code:
the `href` of the the 'state' div should be `#target2` instead of `target2`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        console.log('triggered');      
        $('#target2').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a id="target0" href="#target1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">something</a>
<div class="collapse" id="target1">
    <a href="#target2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">state<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="target2">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">name</a>
    </div>
</div>
```